# Different ssh port than 22 on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I recently changed port field with custom port `sshd_config` file on amazon ec2.

However, it doesn't respond to `ssh -p1234 user@domain.com` because of security groups.

I have my ssh port (22) open on security group but I need to make it `1234` but on aws console, when I changed ssh source to `0.0.0.0/1234` it says unable to find group.

So, how do I set security group right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have confused the port with the CIDR address.

The CIDR annotation describes the range of addresses which are permitted to establish connections on a port - if you want anyone to be able to access the port from any address, use 0.0.0.0/0.

You then specify the port separately, which in your case is 1234.

Comment: I've added custom TCP rule which includes `port` as 1234 in security groups. That solved my problem. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

Please note that changing your ssh port is not considered as a best practice. Network scanners will find your 'hidden' ssh port in no time. It is actually worse than having ssh on 22 since it provides you with false sense of security.

Consider restricting the actual scope of this service to your home / office IP addresses (as instructed by AWS Trusted Advisor)
You can even utilize [Dome9](http://dome9.com) to have this port normally closed and only opened on demand.

(disclaimer: I'm a proud Dome9'er)

Comment: what is best practice, say, if I am on a network that blocks outbound connections to port 22

Comment: There is no problem with changing the SSH port. The problem is by thinking that this will hide it form hackers. If you cannot send traffic to port 22 from your client network then change the SSH port or use a VPN or a proxy hosted on another network.